ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : password popup on new server
We are moving to a new Windows Server 2022 and when using Swagger, some users are experiencing a popup window asking for username and password when trying to run an operation. Others are able to run the exact same operation without getting the popup. Doesn't seem to matter as to Chrome / Edge, both of which are current versions.
If the user enters a valid U/P the operation completes without issue.
As best as I've been able to determine all the settings are the same between the servers.
Anyone have any ideas? Searched but haven't come up with anything worthwhile.
ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, hosted in IIS

What user name is using inthe popup? This determines the authentication scheme userd for the web api. If you are entering the currenet signed-in windows user account. Then it might relate to windows authentication. Then just checking in IIS whether the application site enabled windows authentication or not.

Username/Password - both blank.
To be clear, I DO NOT want the popup at all.
IIS Authentication is ENABLED for Anonymous, Windows at Site/Application.
I am using Windows Authentication as indicated here
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
public class IISDefaults
    public const string AuthenticationScheme = "Windows";

The user credentials should flow from the browser to the API.
This works fine on the old server but seems to be hit or miss on the new server depending on the user.

Enabling windows authencation requires to set it in IIS. And after enabling windows authentication, the first time visit the website will be asked to enter windows user account  and password, after that it won't require to pop up a dialog to sign in again.
